# jOuery Mobile navbar does not divide the space evenly

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a navbar with three links as follows:

**jQuery script references:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

**jQuery-mobile HTML:**

```
    <div data-role="page" id="mobiles">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
            <h1>Seashore Mobiles by Ron Tornambe</h1>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" target="_blank" data-count="true" data-url="' + this.href + '"></a>
            <div class="fb-like" data-share="true" data-width="128" data-show-faces="false" style="margin-left:8px;"></div>
            <div data-role="header" >
                <div data-role="navbar">
                  <ul>
                        <li><a href="#mobiles" data-mini="false" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" data-icon="info">Mobiles</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact" data-icon="info">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about" data-icon="info">About</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
...
    </div>
```

But instead of dividing the space evenly amongst the three link buttons, the buttons are about an inch wide, as seen [on this website](http://mobiles.bunkerhill.com/).

I have been staring at this code for hours and will surly appreciate more sets of eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your styles section on the page you have the following entry:

```
   div a {
       position: relative;
       float: left;
   }
```

The float: left is causing the problem as it is applying to the navbar buttons.